# My iPhone front camera won't work (it freezes)

Tags: iphone

I dropped my phone in the water and everything works, except my front facing camera. When I go to change from back to front, it freezes and won't let me go back to the back camera, and it's blurry.

Comment: Guess you better take it to the store and get a new one.

Comment: You are a good candidate for Apple Store to get some repairs done, since there is nothing we can do for you.

Comment: Take it to the nearest apple service center and replace it.. You dont have any other option..

Answer (score -2):

Deleted Pinterest, suddenly works for me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [answer] for tips on providing a good answer.  We prefer answers to be more than just 1 line, especially when the answer doesn't seem to match the original issue.  For example, please explain how deleting Pinterest would fix a camera issue such as this.